# Parsing json response from c# Generic List

Tags: jquery, .net, json, webmethod

I have jquery ajax call , and this is the code for successful response

```
success: function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg.d);
                    var Ticket = msg.d;
                    console.log(Ticket);
                }
```

The first console.log returns an object of exactly what I want, here is a part of what it looks like in console.

```
[
Object
CouponCode: null
DateCreated: "10/31/2012 12:00:00 AM"
EndDate: "11/23/2012"
EventID: "47c30437-fb5a-461f-9990-a95cc23f1d55"
```

The actual ajax response from webmethod.

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Ticket","rsID":"240bac97-b97b-4d89-ac48-cd692c66a7ad","EventID":"47c30437-fb5a-461f-9990-a95cc23f1d55","Title":  ....
```

How can I access this object?? you see from the console response , now I want the `EventID`

and

```
var Ticket = msg.d;  //this is what I showed from console
var Ticket = $.parseJSON(msg.d);  //returns null
console.log(Ticket.EventID);  //returns null
console.log(Ticket);  // returns null
```

How can I access this `msg.d` ???>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an array of objects, and Ticket is a reference to that array. Even if there is only one object in it, you will need to reference that in the array. Try this:

```
console.log(Ticket[0].EventID);
```

Comment: Damn... I just got done telling someone about how smart I was too :(   , well 25 easy points for you

Comment: @ScottSelby - Well you setup the service and managed to return  serialized json. Looks good to me, just got caught up on something simple. Happens to everyone :)